# Should Overload Resolution Select Private Methods?

Tags: java

Consider this code:

```
class Foo {
    public void doIt(String... strs) {
        System.out.println("this is varargs");
    }

    private void doIt(String str) {
        System.out.println("this is single");
    }
}

class Bar {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new Foo().doIt("");
    }
}
```

With javac version 1.6.0_29, it fails to compile, stating:

```
VarArgsError.java:14: doIt(java.lang.String) has private access in Foo
  new Foo().doIt("");
           ^
1 error
```

Yes, this is silly code and there are at least two obvious workarounds, but I'm curious. Based on [section 15.12.2 of the specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2), this compilation error seems like a bug in javac, because the first step should remove the non-varargs doIt, as it is inaccessible according to [section 6.6.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#104285). Am I missing some other details in the lookup algorithm or is this as obviously wrong as I think it is?

Comment: For completeness, what was the error?

Comment: That was a weird copy/paster error, thanks for catching it. I've edited it in.

Comment: Ran the same code on JDK 1.6.0_23 and didn''t receive the error (I know you did it on _29, but tested anyway)

Comment: `javac` 1.7.0_01 compiles it without errors.

Comment: I can confirm the compile error on 1.6.0_29 on MacOS, and I agree that it is in violation of the spec.

Comment: Exactly the same: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6746184

Comment: Maybe you should answer your own question, noting that it's a bug in the compiler, and then mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not missing anything.
This is a known bug.

As [Qwe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513342/qwe) commented, here is a link to an appropriate bug filing:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6746184

Comment: Thanks, I searched their bug tracker but couldn't find it.